# Connect 2+ LANs into a Single LAN and Access LAN Remotely

Tags: networking, router, vlan, local-area-network

I have two Ubiquiti Dream Machines (just upgraded from Netgear and I am blown away by the difference in quality.) I have one of the Dream Machine routers at home and one at my office, each with its own Internet service provider. My goals are to:

1. Create a single LAN (VLAN?) of which all of the devices both home and office belong, so that I can access any machine using its LAN address from either location. E.g., having a server at work (10.0.1.10) accessible from my PC at home (10.0.0.10). I would like to do this without using a VPN, just having it work.
2. When traveling, be able to connect my laptop to my LAN (via VPN?) and access either the server at work (10.0.1.10) or the PC at home (10.0.0.10).

It seems like this should be possible as it is probably a common enterprise requirement, but I have never done it before. I Googled but have not found any examples on how to configure this. One core issue may also be how DHCP would be handled, especially when a new device joins the network.

So my questions are:

1. Is this configuration possible?
2. Can you point me in the right direction as far as terminology and what I would need to do to set it up?
3. Bonus: can I add more routers and extend my LAN to 3+ locations?

Thanks!

Comment: VPN is a thing. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your home network and office network via a VPN. Then your home network router would send traffic to `10.0.1.0/24` via office VPN server and office network router would send traffic to `10.0.0.0/24` via home VPN server.

Adding further locations / components is possible, you need to have similar router's with VPN tunnels set up and routing rules for all the other networks.